# Criar um arquivo css com classes Bootstrap

Tags: css

desculpem pela pergunta tosca, mas comecei agora com css e estou com uma dúvida:
Terei que repetir fazer várias DIVS (com os mesmos estilos panel e bg-blue-grey-100 do bootstrap) em várias pages. Como eu faço para colocar esses dois estilos em um arquivo css e referenciá-los na minha div?

Um abraço!

```js
 <div class="panel bg-blue-grey-100">
 </div>
```

Comment: O certo seria você aprender SASS, é um pré-compilador CSS, onde permite que você reaproveite os estilos de classes e monte outras, vai te abrir diversas oportunidades para reaproveitamento de estilos.

Comment: Ao contrário do amigo Gustavo eu te aconselho a aprender o CSS puro, sem pre processador, depois que vc estiver bom nos basico e nos fundamentos ai vc parte pra SCSS, SASS etc. Até pq para isso que vc precisa fazer o ideal é um override de css, ou seja um CSS a parte, e não mexer direto no SASS original do Bootstrap

Comment: Cara essas duas classe que vc citou `panel` e `bg-blue-grey-100` não exitem no CSS original do Bootstrap como vc pode ver nesse link https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa

Comment: É que eu estou usando um packge bootstrap de estilos prontos (Theme)... Lá falava que era bootstrap.... Site: https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes/admin